# Android WebView inside ListView should zoom and pan

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, webview, scrollview

So I'm making a layout that looks sort of like this:

```
|----------------|
|                |
|    WebView     |
|                |
|----------------|
|  List element  |
|----------------|
|  List element  |
|----------------|
|  List element  |
|----------------|
|  List element  |
|----------------|
```

I want to have my WebView scroll up along with the List elements, so i made a ListView where the first element is the webview. Main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/overview_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And a WebView element layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/overview_cell_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So far, so good. It shows the webview, but panning and zooming does not work very well. Its "sluggish". You can pan or zoom a very small distance before the gesture is dropped, and zooming/panning comes to a halt. You need to pinch over and over again, to achieve a large zoom level.

I have attempted to resolve this using mainly the requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(), but so far without success. Am i supposed to set it on the webview? The LinearLayout that contains the webview? or something else entirely?

What is the proper way to achieve this, where my webview is zoom-able but still scrolls along with the list elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

main.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

mainactivity:

```
    public class Test extends Activity {

        static String[] month ={
                "January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, month));
            getListViewSize(listView);
        }

        public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
            ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
            if (myListAdapter == null) {
                //do nothing return null
                return;
            }
            //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
                View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            //setting listview item in adapter
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

    }
```